# Proof Using Strong Reducibility

Tags: computability, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

I read the following proof so many times and I could not, for the life of me, figure out how the professor went from (1) to (2).

I know to prove

$\overline{K} \le A$ , where $\overline{K}=\{x:\phi_x(x)\uparrow\}$ and $\phi_i(x) =$ the universal function theorem $h(i, x)$

"$\overline{K}$ is strongly reducible to $A$ where the reduction is effected by $f$"

We have to find a $f$ such that $x \in \overline{K}\equiv f(x)\in A$.

$\psi(x,y)$ in (2) is not such an $f$, and neither is it a verifier for $\overline{K}$. Rather, I think it's a verifier for $K$, the halting set (complete opposite). So I don't know what it's doing here.

Can someone tell me why $\psi(x,y)$ is created and how it is created?

**Edit 1:** $0$ is true, $1$ is false, $\downarrow$ means defined, $\uparrow$ means undefined (loops forever), $P_*$ is the set of semi-recursive relations.

**Original Text Below:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "semi-recursive."  I *am* familiar with the term "recursively enumerable."  From context, I think the two are synonymous.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, semi-recursive = semi-decidable = semi-solvable, meaning we can decide the membership of a valid input that's in the relation (by outputting true, 0), but invalid inputs loops forever (cannot output false, 1). Halting set, K, is semi-decidable/semi-recursive.